# MySQL Trigger that calls a procedure for setting a date

Tags: mysql, triggers, procedure

i have a trigger which set a date if the date isnt set in the insert statement like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER checkData
BEFORE INSERT ON students
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.schoolDate is null THEN
        SET NEW.schooldate=date(now());
    END IF;
END;
```

That works well. But now i want to include this in a procedure like this:

```
create procedure checkdate(setDate date)
begin
    if setDate is null then
                set setDate = date(now());
    end if;
END;
```

And i changed the trigger to:

```
CREATE TRIGGER checkData
BEFORE INSERT ON students
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    call checkdate(NEW.schoolDate);
END;
```

But this doesnt work anymore can any1 help?

Comment: Alternative approach: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a default value instead of a trigger. Change the table structure to

```
create table students
(
    ...
    schoolDate datetime not null default current_timestamp,
    ...
)
```

Then you can insert data with a date set and if you don't provide a date, then the default will be used.

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to solve this with a trigger? I'm just wondering why my solution isn't working.

Comment: My guess is that you give the procedure a value and not a reference. The value gets copied into the procedure and there gets changed and the original column you want to change is not affected by that,